# Possible to implement a manual increment with just simple SQL INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, language-agnostic, insert

I have a primary key that I don't want to auto increment (for various reasons) and so I'm looking for a way to simply increment that field when I INSERT. By simply, I mean without stored procedures and without triggers, so just a series of SQL commands (preferably one command).

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO Table1(id, data_field)
VALUES ( (SELECT (MAX(id) + 1) FROM Table1), '[blob of data]');

COMMIT TRAN;

* Data abstracted to use generic names and identifiers
```

However, when executed, the command errors, saying that

> "Subqueries are not allowed in this
>   context. only scalar expressions are
>   allowed"

So, how can I do this/what am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Since it was pointed out as a consideration, the table to be inserted into is guaranteed to have at least 1 row already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You understand that you will have collisions right?

you need to do something like this and this might cause deadlocks so be very sure what you are trying to accomplish here

```
DECLARE @id int
BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT @id = MAX(id) + 1 FROM Table1 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
    INSERT INTO Table1(id, data_field)
    VALUES (@id ,'[blob of data]')
COMMIT TRAN
```

To explain the collision thing, I have provided some code

first create this table and insert one row

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(id int primary key not null, data_field char(100))
GO
Insert Table1 values(1,'[blob of data]')
Go
```

Now open up two query windows and run this at the same time

```
declare @i int
set @i =1
while @i < 10000
begin
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO Table1(id, data_field)
SELECT MAX(id) + 1, '[blob of data]' FROM Table1

COMMIT TRAN;
set @i =@i + 1
end
```

You will see a bunch of these

Server: Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 7
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Table1__3213E83F2962141D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table1'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Why would there be collisions? Such things are handled by the transaction, yes? Additionally, where would the deadlocks come from?

Comment: not if you run under the default transactional level (read commited), what prohibits two threads to read the same max value?

Comment: Deadlocks can be avoided by omitting the `Holdlock` hint

Comment: why will there be deadlocks?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id, data_field)
SELECT id, '[blob of data]' FROM (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 as id FROM Table1) tbl
```

I wouldn't recommend doing it that way for any number of reasons though (performance, transaction safety, etc)

Comment: What would you recommend they do instead?

Comment: Since the id field is indexed, is the performance hit significant? Also, if wrapped in a transaction, it should be atomic and safe, correct?

Comment: I'm just not sure if the table will be locked when you do the SELECT MAX(id).. part.  If not, there's the potential that two threads could get the same id.  Someone who knows SQL server a bit better would be able to tell you if that is actually safe or not - my intuition is that it isn't, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: The SELECT MAX(ID) statement, in and of itself, is atomic (it's a single transaction).

Comment: I provided code that will show that this will collide if you run it in a loop from 2 different connections

Answer (score 2):

It could be because there are no records so the sub query is returning NULL...try

```
INSERT INTO tblTest(RecordID, Text) 
VALUES ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RecordID), 0) + 1 FROM tblTest), 'asdf')
```

Comment: In this case, it is guaranteed that there is at least one existing row, but good thing to remember. +1

Comment: you can't have a query inside VALUES

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if somebody is still looking for an answer but here is a solution that seems to work:

```
-- Preparation: execute only once
    CREATE TABLE Test (Value int)

CREATE TABLE Lock (LockID uniqueidentifier)
INSERT INTO Lock SELECT NEWID()

-- Real insert

    BEGIN TRAN LockTran

    -- Lock an object to block simultaneous calls.
    UPDATE  Lock WITH(TABLOCK)
    SET     LockID = LockID

    INSERT INTO Test
    SELECT ISNULL(MAX(T.Value), 0) + 1
    FROM Test T

    COMMIT TRAN LockTran
```

Comment: This works however it's not the same as incementing integers. Natually guids will always be unique, but it will be random and not sequential.

Comment: There is a simplification of the code you have done without any needs of transaction scope... See my code below.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation where we needed to increment and could not have gaps in the numbers.  (If you use an identity value and a transaction is rolled back, that number will not be inserted and you will have gaps because the identity value does not roll back.)

We created a separate table for last number used and seeded it with 0.

Our insert takes a few steps.

--increment the number
Update dbo.NumberTable
set number = number + 1

--find out what the incremented number is
select @number = number
from dbo.NumberTable

--use the number
insert into dbo.MyTable using the @number

commit or rollback

This causes simultaneous transactions to process in a single line as each concurrent transaction will wait because the NumberTable is locked.  As soon as the waiting transaction gets the lock, it increments the current value and locks it from others.  That current value is the last number used and if a transaction is rolled back, the NumberTable update is also rolled back so there are no gaps.

Hope that helps.

Another way to cause single file execution is to use a SQL application lock.  We have used that approach for longer running processes like synchronizing data between systems so only one synchronizing process can run at a time.

Comment: You raise a good point about rollbacks. But what prevents two threads from getting the same number? Are you are using a serializable transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in a trigger, you could make sure it's an "INSTEAD OF" trigger and do it in a couple of statements:

```
DECLARE @next INT
SET @next = (SELECT (MAX(id) + 1) FROM Table1)

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES (@next, inserted.datablob)
```

The only thing you'd have to be careful about is concurrency - if two rows are inserted at the same time, they could attempt to use the same value for @next, causing a conflict.

Does this accomplish what you want?

Comment: No, triggers can't be used unless there is no other way.

Comment: @Sql_Ryan
I am using below query for my scenario which is similar to this question. need your valuable suggestion
insert into test_1(id,key_id,name)  
select id,(select max(id) + 1 from test_1),name from test_2
inner join test_1 on test_2.id=test_1.id;

but as you comment I am getting same value for key_id column. Is there any other work around to 
increment column while insert through join statement getting more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very odd to do this sort of thing w/o an IDENTITY (auto-increment) column, making me question the architecture itself. I mean, seriously, this is the perfect situation for an IDENTITY column. It might help us answer your question if you'd explain the reasoning behind this decision. =)

Having said that, some options are:

- using an INSTEAD OF trigger for this purpose. So, you'd do your INSERT (the INSERT statement would not need to pass in an ID). The trigger code would handle inserting the appropriate ID. You'd need to use the WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) syntax used by another answerer to hold the lock for the duration of the trigger (which is implicitly wrapped in a transaction) & to elevate the lock type from "shared" to "update" lock (IIRC).
- you can use the idea above, but have a table whose purpose is to store the last, max value inserted into the table. So, once the table is set up, you would no longer have to do a SELECT MAX(ID) every time. You'd simply increment the value in the table. This is safe provided that you use appropriate locking (as discussed). Again, that avoids repeated table scans every time you INSERT.
- use GUIDs instead of IDs. It's much easier to merge tables across databases, since the GUIDs will always be unique (whereas records across databases will have conflicting integer IDs). To avoid page splitting, sequential GUIDs can be used. This is only beneficial if you might need to do database merging.
- Use a stored proc in lieu of the trigger approach (since triggers are to be avoided, for some reason). You'd still have the locking issue (and the performance problems that can arise). But sprocs are preferred over dynamic SQL (in the context of applications), and are often much more performant.

Sorry about rambling. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any critiques of this?  Works for me.

```
DECLARE @m_NewRequestID INT
        , @m_IsError BIT = 1
        , @m_CatchEndless INT = 0

WHILE @m_IsError = 1
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT  @m_NewRequestID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RequestID), 0) + 1 FROM Requests)

        INSERT INTO Requests (  RequestID
                                , RequestName
                                , Customer
                                , Comment
                                , CreatedFromApplication)
            SELECT  RequestID = @m_NewRequestID
                    , RequestName = dbo.ufGetNextAvailableRequestName(PatternName)
                    , Customer = @Customer
                    , Comment = [Description]
                    , CreatedFromApplication = @CreatedFromApplication
                FROM    RequestPatterns
                WHERE   PatternID = @PatternID

        SET @m_IsError = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @m_IsError = 1
        SET @m_CatchEndless = @m_CatchEndless + 1
        IF @m_CatchEndless > 1000
            THROW 51000, '[upCreateRequestFromPattern]: Unable to get new RequestID', 1
    END CATCH
```

Comment: It's hacky, over-complex, unnecessarily procedural, brute force-dependent, unscalable, inelegant and unprofessional. It relies on exception handling for its default execution path; it couldn't handle more than a few hundred records before it started to slow down. If you put this live in a production environment you would end up waiting potentially several minutes for the creation of a single record. TL;DR don't ever use this script.

Comment: Sometimes you find yourself in a complete jam, at the focal point of historic wrongs, inflexible third party systems and incompatible expectations. In those moments you sometimes find that hacky, over-complex, unnecessarily procedural, brute force-dependent, unscalable, inelegant and unprofessional solutions come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a separate table to maintain the counter? It has better performance than `MAX(id)`, as it will be O(1).  `MAX(id)` is at best O(lgn) depending on the implementation.

And then when you need to insert, simply lock the counter table for reading the counter and increment the counter. Then you can release the lock and insert to your table with the incremented counter value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate table where you keep your latest ID and for every transaction get a new one.
It may be a bit slower but it should work.

```
DECLARE @NEWID INT
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE TABLE SET ID=ID+1
SELECT @NEWID=ID FROM TABLE
COMMIT TRAN

PRINT @NEWID -- Do what you want with your new ID
```

Comment: There is a simplification of the code you have done without any needs of transaction scope... See my code below

Answer (score 0):

Code without any transaction scope (I use it in my engineer course as an exercice) :

```
-- Preparation: execute only once
CREATE TABLE increment (val int);
INSERT INTO increment VALUES (1);

-- Real insert
DECLARE @newIncrement INT;

UPDATE increment
SET    @newIncrement = val,
       val = val + 1;

INSERT INTO Table1 (id, data_field)
SELECT @newIncrement, 'some data';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @nextId int
set @nextId = (select MAX(id)+1 from Table1)

insert into Table1(id, data_field) values (@nextId, '[blob of data]')

commit;
```

But perhaps a better approach would be using a scalar function getNextId('table1')

Comment: getNextId(<Table>) would be a..custom stored procedure, or an included one? If included, what platforms is it on, since I don't think it is standard.

Comment: So your function would use dynamic SQL? Or a separate key table?

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id, data_field)
SELECT (SELECT (MAX(id) + 1) FROM Table1), '[blob of data]';
```

Or this (substitute LIMIT for other platforms):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id, data_field)
SELECT TOP 1
    MAX(id) + 1, '[blob of data]'
FROM
   Table1
ORDER BY
   [id] DESC;
```

Comment: Any comment on why -1 from someone?

Comment: Drive-by downvoter probably meant that this query will produce duplicate ids in a high concurrency environment.