# Insert identity script

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have a table, the first column is an identity. I thought that the value was increated by one automatelly. 
Say I have this column as

```
1 
2
3
4
...
47
48
49
50
```

If I delete the last row(id = 50) and insert a new row, why the identity is 51 rather than 50?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is used up whether the row exists or not. In addition to deletes, you will also see gaps when an insert is rolled back. If you want a contiguous sequence of integers, identity is not the answer.

Comment: Can I SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE ON to enforce no gap?

Comment: What would be the point? If you don't want gaps, just don't use an identity in the first place. Why do you care about gaps? These are just meaningless, surrogate keys, right? If you care about gaps *for a reason* then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/794628/61305).

Comment: @Love Never use SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE ON in production code that runs all the time, teh purpose fo r this is to do one time inserts from another system. Only a dba should ever use this.

Answer (score 0):

The identity seed is not affected by the delete, so the next value will continue to increment as if the row was never deleted.

Identities can also be reseeded using the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) utility.

Comment: Where is the value stored? In system table?

Comment: @Love SQL Server essentially holds a cache of values to dole out in memory; when it exhausts those, it gets more. You can retrieve the current value for a table using IDENT_CURRENT() but please do not attempt to use this to adjust for gaps.

Answer (score 0):

The seed is kept track of separately from the records; if you delete the record, the value was still used.  You can use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (YourTable, NORESEED)
```

to verify what the next identity value will be.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to try adjust for gaps. If you do not do it correctly, you are highly likely to end up with data integrity issues. There is no reason to care about there being gaps in 99.99% of all applications (there are a few applications with a legal requirement that doesn't allow gaps - those do not use identity).