# Inserting into a primary key field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to increment an `ID` field that has a primary key in an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement? 
What I would want to do is take the last `ID` of the table and insert an incremented `ID` with each new record produced by the `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what you're trying to do? I'm not sure if you're talking about an identity column or something that could/should use a seqentialID or use one of the post insert Identity variables.

Comment: Your ID field is a IDENTITY? If so, this is automatically done.

Comment: Unfortunately, IDENTITY isn't going to work for me due to other constraints.  Thank you though.

Comment: not sure the your question is clear ! You want that when doing 'insert into' the value of the new id would be the same sa the one in the mother table ?

Comment: The ID field is not an IDENTITY field and cannot be due to other constraints, but it has a primary key constraint on the ID field.  What I want to do is take data from table B and insert into table A.  However, due to the PK on the ID column, I need to have an ID value and maintain the ID order.

Comment: Read here about the [`IDENTITY VALUES`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: @ghoston3rd If you're doing manual sequencing, be careful about which isolation level you're using.

Comment: In that case you don't need any increment. Is just a plain insert select, and table B must have a PK (which is clustered/ordered in SQL Server). But the order simple don't have any importance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to implement a manual increment with just simple SQL INSERT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794577/possible-to-implement-a-manual-increment-with-just-simple-sql-insert)

Comment: I was running into the collisions as described in the answer of [Possible to implement a manual increment with just simple SQL INSERT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794577/possible-to-implement-a-manual-increment-with-just-simple-sql-insert)

Comment: try to acquire `XLOCK`s on the max row in conjunction with the `serializable` isolation level, but you might get deadlocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @lastId int = 0
SELECT @lastId = MAX(Id) From YourTable 

INSERT INTO YourTable (Id, Data)
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))) + @lastId, at.Data
FROM AnotherTable at
```

Be sure to add it inside a Transaction scope.

SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d23642/5

Anyway I strongly suggest you to use an IDENTITY column to avoid collisions.

Comment: Which [isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) do you need to be running at to make this work?

Comment: I would say READ_COMMITTED at least, if is a recurrent job.

Comment: @VitorTyburski Yes, but you are not protected from collisions. Both threads read committed last id, increment it and try to insert, one of them gets the collision error.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't be. If executed, it should not be done in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get the max id and then increse in one on each Insert

```
INSERT MAX(ID)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you are looking for.  Let's assume the PK is an INT for demo purposes.

```
--Get the last/greatest PK value in first table.
DECLARE @LastPKValue INT
SELECT @LastPKValue = MAX(PKCol)
FROM [schema].[YourTable]

INSERT INTO [schema].[YourTable] (PKCol, ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER()  OVER( ORDER BY sot.[SomeColumnName]) + @LastPKValue, 
    OtherColumnA, 
    OtherColumnB, 
    OtherColumnC
FROM [schema].[SomeOtherTable] sot
```